# Django model xor'd OneToOnes

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Django model scenario:

```
class A(models.Model)
    pass

class B(models.Model)
    a = models.OneToOne(A)

class C(models.Model)
    a = models.OneToOne(A)

class D(models.Model)
    a = models.OneToOne(A)
```

Is there a way to guarantee that only one instance of any given B, C, or D object will only point to a single A object? So for example, if there is an instance of B that points to an instance of A, then no other object may point to that instance of A.

Comment: If you have control over the model definitions then you might have a cleaner way of implementing this with django's model inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to jump through some hoops to make this work.

You could create a custom `save` method on `B`, `C`, and `D` which loads the instance of `A` to which you are trying to point to from the DB and makes sure that no instances of the other models exist.